# Highcharts: Ugly Candlesticks

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts

My Candlestick chart imports data from a json file. Everything is great when I don't mess with the file

[image: Original Timeframe Candlestick]

But when I use php to exclude some json rows to filter the data, I will end up with this even when every value on chart is correct.

[image: Ugly Candlestick]

How can I fix it?

My settings

```
(function () {
//    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?a=e&filename=aapl-ohlc.json&callback=?', function (data) {
            $.getJSON(<?php echo "'getJSON.php?symbol=" . $_GET["symbol"] . "&timeframe=" . $_GET["timeframe"] . "'"; ?>, function (data) {

        // create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1,
                                buttons: [{
                                    type: 'minute',
                                    count: 1,
                                    text: '1m'
                                }, {
                                    type: 'minute',
                                    count: 5,
                                    text: '5m'
                                }, {
                                    type: 'minute',
                                    count: 30,
                                    text: '30m'
                                }, {
                                    type: 'hour',
                                    count: 1,
                                    text: '1h'
                                }, {
                                    type: 'hour',
                                    count: 5,
                                    text: '5h'
                                }, {
                                    type: 'all',
                                    text: 'All'
                                }]
            },

            title : {
                text : <?php echo "'" . $_GET["symbol"] . " Price | " . $_GET["timeframe"] . "M'" ?>
            },

            series : [{
                type : 'candlestick',
                name : <?php echo "'" . $_GET["symbol"] . " Price'"; ?>,
                data : data,
                dataGrouping : {
                                    enable: false
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes that doesn't look right. Is there a question here?

Comment: @BenPearlKahan How can I fix it?

Comment: We need to see your code otherwise we can't tell what's wrong

Comment: @BenPearlKahan Added.

Comment: How your json data looks like ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan [1446648660000,1.09332,1.09348,1.09328,1.09341],  first one is timestamp and others are prices. I just removed some rows to filter timestamp, So the data is same

Comment: @SebastianBochan As you can see, In both images the navigator line charts are exactly same

Comment: Im a little bit confused, when you remove some candles / points, the Highstock prints data according to series which you define. So what is wrong?

Comment: @SebastianBochan Everthing is fine except that the candlesticks are very small and are not displayed as first image

Comment: Replace dataGrouping : {
                                    enable: false
                } with dataGrouping : {
                                    enabled: false
                }

Comment: @SebastianBochan Not worked.

Comment: Try to call [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes) on yAxis / xAxis to update range on axis.